# Show $\operatorname{Homeo}(S^1)$ is not locally compact

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, lie-groups

I'm asked to show as an exercise that $\operatorname{Homeo}(S^1)$ is not locally compact when endowed with the compact-open topology. I'd appreciate a hint as a start, please, because I don't have much inspiration with this.

Comment: With what topology is $Homeo(S^1)$ endowed?

Comment: The compact-open topology. Sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: Well, as a start, apply the definitions to restate what you have to prove. Did you get that far?

Comment: *Hint*: the compact-open topology is the topology of uniform convergence in this case.

Comment: *Hint* : find a sequence of homeomorphisms which converges pointwise to something, but does not converge uniformly

Comment: Well, I tried several sequences so far, but I think I need a more complex one than the easy examples we use normally, don’t I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

As $S^1$ is a compact metric space, the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) of $\operatorname{Homeo}(S^1)$ is the one of $\operatorname{Homeo}(S^1)$ endowed with the metric topology of the uniform convergence.

Now consider the identity map $\operatorname{Id}$ of $\operatorname{Homeo}(S^1)$ and a sequence of maps that is constant on $S^1 \setminus B(-1, \epsilon)$ and stretch more and more a ruban band on $S^1 \cap B(-1, \epsilon)$, where $B(-1, \epsilon)$ denotes the ball centered on $-1 \in \mathbb C$ with radius equal to $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint!